# How do I create a binary format file compatible with PostgreSQL Copy?

Tags: java, postgresql

I wrote a java program to create a binary file compatible with PostgreSQL Copy command by using help from the following StackOverflow post:

[Java library to write binary format for Postgres COPY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242117/java-library-to-write-binary-format-for-postgres-copy)

I have a Postgres table column **character varying(1)** which can be **null**. Basically, this is 1 character field which can be null. so, how can I convert **null** into a binary string? I used the following way to convert but **null** is 4-character long. It is working fine with CSV file format but it's not working with a BINARY file format. Any idea will be appreciated.

```
String nullStr = "null";
strBytes = nullStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: `null` is not the same as `"null"`, i.e. the second one is an actual string.

Comment: Don't go that way. Use the text format. Do you think it is much faster if you convert the data to binary format in your Java code than it is for the PostgreSQL server to do so in C? Also don't forget that the binary format depends on the architecture of the server...

Comment: yeah, use text or CSV format.

Comment: thanks all. actually, I am currently using text format. I want to check the performance of binary format. I am just using Java to create the file but this file will be used in postgres.